# After read file, echo command not found

Tags: bash, echo, ifs

I am sure this a duplicate, but my search for relevant info went without finding anything.

I was using mapfile to read a file in, but the appliances I need to run the script on do not have it loaded.  So I went for an alternative.

This is not my script, but a test script to prove my point.

I have a file that has a bunch of stats, shorten below for sanity.

```
Status                   
 Availability     : available
 State            : enabled
 Reason           : The virtual server is available
 CMP              : enabled
 CMP Mode         : all-cpus


Traffic                    ClientSide  Ephemeral  General
 Bits In                           0          0        -
 Bits Out                          0          0        -
 Packets In                        0          0        -
 Packets Out                       0          0        -
 Current Connections               0          0        -
 Maximum Connections               0          0        -
 Total Connections                 0          0        -
 Min Conn Duration/msec            -          -        0
 Max Conn Duration/msec            -          -        0
 Mean Conn Duration/msec           -          -        0
 Total Requests                    -          -        0
```

I am using the following code to read in the file into an array (I want to use this array multiple times in the script).  But upon echoing out line by line.  I get command not found on each line.  I cannot figure out how to resolve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

getArray() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}

infile="/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt"

file=getArray $infile

for i in ${file[@]};
do :
    echo "$i"
done
```

results in the following

```
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 1: Status: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 2: Availability: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 3: State: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 4: Reason: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 5: CMP: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 6: CMP: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 9: Traffic: command not found
/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt: line 10: Bits: command not found
```

I've tried double qouting $i, single qouting $i, and qouting / unqouting the array.  Nothing I've tried has resulted in anything but :command not found

Comment: Likely you are getting unintended word splitting which Bash is interpreting as a command. Try `for i in "${file[@]}";` You also have a stray `:` after `do`

Comment: just updated my code and double qoutes the array.  still same result :(

Comment: `for i in "${file[@]}";
do :
 echo "$i"
done`  results in command not found

Comment: You still have an extra `:` Also, `file=getArray $infile` does not work since there is no return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
getArray() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}

infile="/tmp/file"
getArray "$infile" # you would need a return value for "file=getArray $infile"
                   # and you would write it differently

for i in "${array[@]}";
do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

You had three issues:

1. `file=getArray $infile` does not return the array read. You would need to change the function and the assignment for that to work
2. You have an extra `:` in your loop.
3. You needs quotes around the array in the for loop to avoid word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

you are right.  I was assuming the function would return the array to $file, but it wasn't.  I create ${file[@]} in the function.

Got it working

```
#!/bin/bash

getArray() {
  file=() # Create array
  while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
  do
      file+=("$line") # Append line to the array
  done < "$1"
}


infile="/home/tony/Desktop/test.txt"
getArray $infile

for i in "${file[@]}";
do :
  echo "$i"
done
```